# "Out of Memory" VBA error after trying to register descriptions of UDFs

Tags: excel, vba, out-of-memory, user-defined-functions

I have created a series of VBA mathematical functions in an Excel spreadsheet (i.e. minimisation algorithms). These functions have been tested and they seem to be working properly. I want to add a description of these function and their arguments therefore, based on [this question on the topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41465478/register-udf-with-descriptions-of-arguments-using-excel-addin), I tried to code some subroutines that would achieve that:

- First, I created a subroutine to actually encapsulate the descriptions:

  ```
  Sub RegisterUDF()

  myFunctionOneDescription = "Long FunctionOne description" & vbLf _ 
      & "myFunctionOne(<...>, ..., <...>)"
  myFunctionOneArguments = Array("FunctionOne argument 1 description", _
                                 "FunctionOne argument 2 description", _
                                 "FunctionOne argument 3 description", _
                                 "FunctionOne argument 4 description", _
                                 "[Optional] FunctionOne argument 5 description")

  myFunctionTwoDescription = "Long FunctionTwo description" & vbLf _ 
      & "myFunctionTwo(<...>, ..., <...>)"
  myFunctionTwoArguments = Array("FunctionTwo argument 1 description", _
                                 "FunctionTwo argument 2 description", _
                                 "FunctionTwo argument 3 description", _
                                 "FunctionTwo argument 4 description", _
                                 "[Optional] FunctionTwo argument 5 description")

  myFunctionThreeDescription = "Long FunctionThree description" & vbLf  _ 
      & "myFunctionThree(<...>, ..., <...>)"
  myFunctionThreeArguments = Array("FunctionThree argument 1 description", _
                                   "FunctionThree argument 2 description", _
                                   "FunctionThree argument 3 description", _
                                   "FunctionThree argument 4 description", _
                                   "[Optional] FunctionThree argument 5 description")

  Application.MacroOptions Macro:="myFunctionOne", Description:=myFunctionOneDescription, ArgumentDescriptions:=myFunctionOneArguments, Category:=9
  Application.MacroOptions Macro:="myFunctionTwo", Description:=myFunctionTwoDescription, ArgumentDescriptions:=myFunctionTwoArguments, Category:=9
  Application.MacroOptions Macro:="myFunctionThree", Description:=myFunctionThreeDescription, ArgumentDescriptions:=myFunctionThreeArguments, Category:=9

  End Sub
  ```
- Then, I create the following subroutine in the ThisWorkbook object:

  ```
  Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Call RegisterUDF
  End Sub
  ```

  so that the descriptions are automatically loaded when I open the workbook.

When creating these two subroutines and assessing the look of the function descriptions in the Function UI (namely the one that pops up when you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> or `fx`), I started closing and reopening the workbook given descriptions are updated only when `Workbook_Open()` is executed. Then, at some point I started getting an `Out of Memory` error immediately after opening the workbook; the error seemed to originate from the third function description above:

[image]

I started getting rid of these two subroutines but now I still see the `Out of Memory` error when I refresh my workbook (whose tabs are populated with instances of my user-defined functions); each time, the `Out of Memory` error seems to originate in one of my UDFs but not always the same. In addition, when I try to cancel the debugging by resetting VBA, I get a new `Out of Memory` error immediately after, before having refreshed the workbook or performed any additional action, thus I end trapped in a "loop" of `Out of Memory` errors and I am forced to close Excel from the Task Manager <sup>(1)</sup>. This had never happened before I tried to code the functions' descriptions.

**Can anybody help me in understanding what might be going on?** I suspect this is related to the utilisation of `Application.MacroOptions` but I am unsure. **Any help is greatly appreciated.**

<sub>(1) I suspect this is actually explained by the fact that, when I refresh the workbook or a tab, multiple instances of my UDFs will try to reevaluate hence each `Out of Memory` error corresponds to one instance of my UDFs.</sub>

**[EDIT #1]** I observe very strange behaviour. For example, on a tab with preexisting instances of my UDFs in some cells, I have tried to evaluate one of my functions in a new cell *after having commented out the 2 subroutines described above*. When writing down the function in the cell and pressing enter, I got the `Out of Memory` error originating from the code of that UDF. Then, I *deleted from the VBA code the **commented** subroutines* and when pressing enter the function evaluated correctly! However, when refreshing that tab, I then got the same memory error but this time coming from another UDF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to have been solved by following the procedure outlined below<sup>(1)</sup>:

1. Delete subroutines `RegisterUDF()` from module and `Workbook_Open()` from Workbook object;
2. Copy all the VBA code from the module<sup>(2)</sup> into e.g. the notepad;
3. Delete the workbook's module;
4. Create a new module in the same workbook;
5. Paste code into new module.

The `Out of Memory` errors have ceased after this manipulation, however I still do not know what the origin was in the first place, and I am not sure whether this could happen again if I try to reprogram `RegisterUDF()` and `Workbook_Open()`. *Any additional explanation to this bug is greatly appreciated.*

<sub>(1) Other tricks, such as copying the whole workbook; restarting the computer; copying/pasting the code to a new workbook without deleting the old module from the original workbook; etc. did not seem to solve the issue.</sub>

<sub>(2) All my code was located in a single module.</sub>